# Classify the growth of poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ group

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, geometric-group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Let $G$ be a poly-$\mathbb{Z}$ group, i.e $$G =(\dots((\mathbb{Z} \rtimes_{\phi_1} \mathbb{Z})\rtimes_{\phi_2} \mathbb{Z}) \rtimes_{\phi_3} \mathbb{Z} \dots ) \rtimes_{\phi_{n-1}} \mathbb{Z}$$ What are the necessary and sufficient conditions $\phi_{n-1}$ needs to have for $G$ to have polynomial growth?

**Thoughts**: we know that $G$ can only have exponential or polynomial growth. According to [this paper](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/26/6/543/400922?redirectedFrom=PDF), $\phi_{n-1}$ corresponds to a matrix $M$ in $ \operatorname{GL}(m, \mathbb{Z})$ for some $m$. I was wondering if there are any known results that allow us to tell the growth of G by looking at this matrix $M$?

Any references for this question would be really appreciated, thanks for reading.

Comment: Polynomial growth is equivalent to the group being virtually nilpotent. Why have you only attached a homomorphism $\phi$ to one of the semidirect products?

Comment: Thanks! I thought we could determine the growth of such groups by looking at the last automorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write $G = G_{n-1}  \rtimes_{\phi_{n-1}} \mathbb{Z}$. Letting $M$ be the identity matrix, equivalently $\phi_{n-1} : \mathbb Z \to \text{Aut}(G)$ is the trivial homomorphism, we obtain a direct product $G = G_{n-1} \times \mathbb Z$. From this it follows that the growths of $G$ and $G_{n-1}$ are equivalent: $G$ has polynomial growth if and only if $G_{n-1}$ does; and $G$ has exponential growth if and only if $G_{n-1}$ does.

Therefore $\phi_{n-1}$ does not determine the growth. To put it another way, there do not exist any conditions on $\phi_{n-1}$ alone which are necessary and sufficient for $G$ to have exponential growth.